# Is it possible to build a collection of Func

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I'm trying to setup a set of dynamic filters to inject in to my ORM object at runtime (one for each entity type) so I'm looking to do something like this:

```
Filters = new List<Action>
{
    (Foo f) => ...,
    (Bar b) => ...,
    (Goo g) => ...,
};
```

Then when the user does something like:

```
var tSet = db.GetAll<T>().Where(...).ToArray();
```

I would implement GetAll() like:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
{
    using var db = Connection.Open();
    var filter = Filters.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(Func<T, bool>)) as Func<T, bool>;

    return (FiltersEnabled && filter != null) ? db.Select<T>().Where(filter) : db.Select<T>();
}
```

Is it possible to store a `List<Func<variousT, bool>>` in some way as I can't seem to make this work?
I've been trying to declare it as:

```
protected ICollection<object> Filters = new List<object>();
```

but that doesn't work, and obviously I can't use `Action` delegates because of the signature differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all your delegates are of different types, you need to declare the collection to contain their *base* type: `Delegate`:

```
List<Delegate> filters = new List<Delegate>
{
    (Func<int, bool>)(i => i > 0),
    (Func<string, bool>)(s => s.Length > 0)
};
```

The explicit cast to `Func` is needed, because the compiler cannot automatically cast a lambda-expression into a `Delegate`.

Comment: I figured as much, I think the key component I was missing was the need for the cast, well spotted thanks :)

Comment: @War You don't need a cast; you can do something like `filters.Add(new Func<double, string>(d => $"Double: {d}"));`

Comment: @MatthewWatson ok that's not a cast, but even more code (characters) than a cast.

Comment: @War If you implement this answer, you may want to use a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` instead of your `List<Delegate>` to improve performance